# Undefined reference to 'SDL_main'

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks

I've recently decided to try working with SDL with CodeBlocks 10.05. I started with the tutorial on http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tutorial-basics and did my best to follow it. Unfortunately, I'm encountering:

```
..\..\..\..\..\..\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\lib\libSDLmain.a(SDL_win32_main.o):SDL_win32_main.c|| undefined reference to `SDL_main'|
```

when I try to compile it.

I've searched through many of the questions on this website and other tutorials (mainly the tutorial on LazyFoo and the CodeBlocks wiki) and can't seem to find a solution.

- C:\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\include has been added in the Compiler tab (Search Directories)
- C:\SDL\SDL-1.2.15\lib has been added in the Linker tab
- The libraries libmingw32.a, libSDLmain.a, libSDL.dll.a are linked in that order

  - libmingw32.a from the MinGW\lib folder in the CodeBlocks installation directory
- SDL.dll is in both the System32 folder and in the project folder

When attempting to follow the tutorial on the CodeBlocks wiki, I was told that SDL.h could not be found in the given directory (when making a new SDL project).

CApp.cpp

```
#include "CApp.h"
#include "SDL\SDL.h"

CApp::CApp(){
    Surf_Display=NULL;

    Running=true;
}

int CApp::OnExecute(){
    if (OnInit()==false){
        return -1;
}

SDL_Event Event;

while (Running){
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&Event)){
        OnEvent(&Event);
    }
    OnLoop();
    OnRender();
}

OnCleanup();
return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    CApp theApp;

    return theApp.OnExecute();
}
```

CApp.h

```
#ifndef CAPP_H_INCLUDED
#define CAPP_H_INCLUDED
#include "SDL\SDL.h"

class CApp{
    private:
        bool Running;
        SDL_Surface* Surf_Display;

    public:
        CApp();
        int OnExecute();

    public:
        bool OnInit();
        void OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event);
        void OnLoop();
        void OnRender();
        void OnCleanup();
};



#endif // CAPP_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: IIRC you need to supply `SDL_main`, instead of having a `main` you have an `SDL_main`

Comment: @Musa

I'm sorry, could you possibly explain what you meant by that? I'm relatively new to programming and don't quite understand. Does this have to do with my setup of SDL (Linking and whatnot) or is it a problem within the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I see this is done in SDL_main.h

Comment: There's got to be something missing in your linker setup. The way you described it, it should work (and it indeed does, for me at least).

Comment: @jrok I just tried redoing all of the linking following what the tutorial stated as well as the points listed above. To walkthrough what I did:


- Downloaded SDL-1.2.15-win32-x64.zip (64-bit Windows) and SDL-devel-1.2.15-mingw32.tar.gz (Mingw32) from the SDL website.
- Extracted the first one into C:\SDL and placed the SDL.dll from the second into the project folder and system32
- Added the \include and \lib in the compiler and linker tabs respectively
- Linked libmingw32.a, libSDLmain.a, and libSDL.dll.a in that order.

Comment: But have you have checked that the *.a libs actually exist in one of the directories the linker sees? You can find them in devel package in `/lib` dir.

Comment: Oh, and make sure you're actually compiling CApp.cpp.

Comment: @jrok I definitely have the .a files mentioned above in the lib folders. There's also ._ versions (e.g. "._libSDLmain.a" as well as the corresponding "libSDLmain.a"). It's extracted right from "SDL-devel-1.2.15-mingw32.tar.gz" available on the SDL website.

I'm just pressing F9 to build and run the project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only plausible reason for your problem I can think of is that when you created the file with `main` in it, you forgot to add it to build targets.

[image]

You should see CApp.cpp in the list where my main.cpp is. Right click on it and click Properties. Click on Build tab in the window that pops up. You should see this:

[image]

Click OK, hit Ctrl+F11 (Rebuild).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe this was the problem!

Comment: Apparently this exact syntax/signature for the `main` function is required. If you just use `int main() { }` like many compilers support, it does not work. If anyone knows why, please let me know.

Answer (score 42):

put these arguments to the main function. I had this problem too, and I fixed it few seconds ago.

int main(int argv, char** args)
{
}

Comment: Thanks! Anyone willing/able to explain why this works (@ me please)?

Comment: @JochemKuijpers this particular signature is required, because SDL alters default program entry point resolving. In normal circumstances, you can use one of many standard signatures for the main function, `int main()`, `void main()`, `int main(int, char**)`, etc. The compiler will accept all these variants. But SDL intercepts the main entry point, as described in my answer, and calls your entry point expecting a specific signature, which is no longer subject to compiler interpretation.

Answer (score 17):

Try `#undef main` after all SDL related headers.

**Update. This is not a valid solution!**

As pointed out by HolyBlackCat, this is a pretty sloppy fix. SDL replaces the main function in order to perform some initialization and/or cleanup that is otherwise not possible, and then calls back to the actual user function.

The interception works by replacing the name of user's main function to `SDL_main`, with a simple macro

```
#define main SDL_main
```

The user's function then ceases to be the entry point for the application, and an entry point provided by SDL is used. The proposed `#undef` disables the interception recklessly and one should argue that it is not supposed to work at all. For those who successfully compiled and ran an SDL application after this "fix", it must have simply been a platform-dependent coincidence.

The proper solution to the OP's error is making sure that the file containing `main` gets compiled and linked, and that the function has correct signature. As already posted by others.

Comment: Still the same problem after trying this.

Comment: YOU'RE KIDDING... I wish I found this an hour earlier.  Worked on OSX.

Comment: Why does this fix the problem??

Comment: Even if it appears to work, one shouldn't do it. SDL has `#define main SDL_main` because it needs to do some initialization in `main()` before executing user code. It may or may not work if you ditch this initialization.

Comment: Sorry for keeping it up for so long. Of course this is not a correct solution. I realized it long ago and wanted to write an update, but I've never had time to develop the full understanding of the problem and why my "solution" works.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I had this problem, watched some YouTube videos and also followed the installation guide by LazyFoo and I kept getting the "Undefined reference to SDL_main" error.

I followed everything said here after successfully linking the minGw files to my project properties, but it didn't work until I added to my main function `int main (int argv, char** args)` and voila, it worked.

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char** args) {    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)<0)    {
       cout<<"Endl Init Failed."<<endl;
       return 1;    }

   cout<<"SDL Init succeeded."<<endl;

   SDL_Quit();    return 0; }
```

Why it worked is still not clear to me but it worked anyway.

Comment: So what exactly did you change? Replaced `int main()` with `int main(int argv, char** args)`?

Comment: Exactly, use that and hopefully, it should work as it is in my case

Comment: We already have an answer suggesting the exact same thing, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: For me `char const *argv[]` did not work but your way did. WTF?

Answer (score 1):

Define `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` before you include the SDL libs:

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>
```

More info: [I'm using the SDL functions without the SDL_main be defined. Is that fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079288/im-using-the-sdl-functions-without-the-sdl-main-be-defined-is-that-fine)

Answer (score 0):

This was the first question that pop out to my search.
None of the solutions worked for me.
Eventually I figured it what worked for me. Will post the my answer here to "any fellow wanderer".

My problem was that I tried to compile some old C game not a C++ one.
One part of the solution for me was to rename the main.c to main.cpp
And then to signal to CMake to use CPP compiler for all C files.
Eventually here is a portion of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
# set minimum cmake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19 FATAL_ERROR)

# project name and language
project(FootballManager LANGUAGES CXX)

# This is mandatory too, because otherwise they are not compiled an linked.
file(GLOB_RECURSE CFILES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.c")
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${CFILES} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)

# list sources
list(APPEND _sources config.h)
# ... removed some of the other sources for brevity ...
list(APPEND _sources misc.c)

# Link SDL, yes this is SDL1.2
find_package(SDL REQUIRED)
include_directories(FootballManager ${SDL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(fm main.cpp ${_sources})

target_link_libraries(fm ${SDL_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0):

Know that SDL1 is outdated and that you should not use it but for whatever reason CodeBlocks still inserts an `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` even if you selected the creation of an SDL2 project so you may need to change that include to `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`