# undefined reference to cell::cell(float)

Tags: c++, codeblocks, undefined-reference

I can't understand why I get the following errors, since I have included all the libraries and everything is more public than it should have been!! Probably it's something I haven't grasped or a stupid mistake.. Could you please help!!

Errors:
"undefined reference to cell::cell(float)"
"undefined reference to exploration::exploration(bool,float,int)"

Disregard the non existent encapsulation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vehicle.h"
#include "tool.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "exploration.h"
#include "analyze.h"
#include "repair.h"
#include "cell.h"

int main()
{
int k=0;
std::vector <cell> cells;
std::vector <Exploration> vexp;
std::vector <analyze> anal;
std::vector <Repair> reps;
srand (time(NULL));

std::cout << "Enter number of cells\n";
std::cin.clear();
std::cin >> k;
r = rand() % 100+1;
for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
{
    cell tempcell (0.1);
    cells.push_back(tempcell);
}
for(int i=1; i<9; i++)
{
    Exploration temp (0,3,3);
    vexp.push_back(temp);
}
}
```

cell.h:

```
#ifndef CELL_H
#define CELL_H
#include<vector>

class cell
{
public:
cell (float);
int Pd;
int Ir;
int Pt;
float Danger;
bool Flag;
bool Occupied;

int RandGround();
void ChangeFlag();
void ChangeGround();
};

#endif // CELL_H
```

cell.cpp:

```
#include "cell.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

cell :: cell (float Dang)
{
Pd = RandGround();
Ir = RandGround();
Pt = RandGround();
Danger = Dang;
Flag = 0;
Occupied = 0;
}


int cell::RandGround()
{
int r;
srand(time(NULL));
return r;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are not linking in `cell.cpp`

Comment: Can you show your full compilation command line?

Comment: @Angew this is it, I have no more feed from the compiler..
in function main:
undefined reference to cell::cell(float)
undefined reference to Exploration::Exploration(bool,float,int)

Comment: @alex777: The question is what are *you* feeding the compiler with?

Comment: Most likely you're not compiling the file with the implementations of `cell` methods. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803918/undefined-reference-to-sdl-main/10821071#10821071)-

Comment: @alex777 I was asking for the command line arguments with which you (or Code::Blocks) invoke the compiler, not for the compiler's (actually linker's) output.

Comment: @AndyProwl I am working in codeblocks, I don't know where to find the compilation command line

Comment: @alex777 Does Code::Blocks have a help?

Comment: @alex777: Try to figure that out then. If your project contains more than one file, make sure they're all linked in when building the executable. Have you defined a project in CB?

Comment: @Angew I got it, mingw32-g++.exe -o bin\Debug\examinou.exe obj\Debug\main.o

Comment: @AndyProwl I got it, mingw32-g++.exe -o bin\Debug\examinou.exe obj\Debug\main.o

Comment: In the GUI I have told to CodeBlocks to compile and link all .cpp and link all .h also...

Comment: You need to include `cell.o`

Comment: @alex777: As I suspected, judging from your command line, it seems you're not linking in the output of `cell.cpp`, which should be `cell.o`.

Comment: jrok answered it, and I lost his comment while writing!! The answer is in the link he gave which I didn't find on my own... sorry for your lost time!!

Comment: Looks like you need to run project re-building to make cell.cpp visible for compile command.