# I'm using the SDL functions without the SDL_main be defined. Is that fine?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

that's my code:

Lib.h

```
#ifdef ExportLib
    #define Lib __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define Lib __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
extern void Lib Launch();
```

Lib.cpp

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include "Lib.h"
void Launch() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("Untitle", 100, 100, 400, 400, 0);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I build this code to a static library. Then I created a new source file and used this library.

main.cpp

```
#include "Lib.h"

int main() {
    Launch();
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, I compile main.cpp using my static library without the SDL_main be defined and the SDL's dependecies. That works fine, the window appears.

But is really fine do it? What functionalities I lost doing it?

Comment: What are your conclusions? Were you losing any functionalities by using your code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`SDL_main` is for SDL's automatic initialization and cleanup.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976084/why-sdl-defines-main-macro) It's mostly so you don't need to do it manually, though it also goes through the effort of properly setting everything up for a windowed application on the platform where it's compiled, but it's [fine](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady) to `#define` the macro `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` before `#include`ing SDL.h, which will prevent SDL from turning `main` into a macro for `SDL_main` Simply make sure to initialize and quit SDL properly inside your own code.

If you want to be sure you're doing the necessary initialization right, you can [just check the source code](http://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows#I_get_.22Undefined_reference_to_.27SDL_main.27.22_...) and emulate what's there.

*Edit:*

On some platforms, [SDL_Init will fail](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryInit) if you don't use `SDL_main`. You can disable this failure by calling `SDL_SetMainReady` before `SDL_Init`, but be aware this will disable SDL's error handling, and if you improperly initialize SDL after calling `SDL_SetMainReady` you won't get the clearest of error messages.

Quitting SDL is [much more straightforward](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryInit) (and also needs to be done if you're not using SDL_main):

Just call [`SDL_Quit`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Quit) when you're done with SDL. This will properly close any SDL subsystems presently active.

Comment: I saw that the entry point is WinMain and then SDL_main is called. I'm confused with that. How could SDL be compiled to a library if the SDL_main wasn't defined? I have tried to emulate this system but the compiler get me a undefined reference to WinMain.

Comment: I'm not sure how they set up the project so it compiles and links, though one can probably figure that out by digging through a source download. I did however go looking, and according to [this thread](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=9151&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0&sid=3043bc6931e9d3732ced6b33516a6286) on the SDL forums (SDL Development>SDL_main, Jun 10, 2013) you may define main *anywhere* in a C program: It just has to exist somewhere, not necessarily in the part of the binary you would think.

Comment: Too bad they don't say _which_ operating systems fail.

Comment: Your link to "just check the source code" does not link to source code...

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using the SDL functions without the SDL_main be defined. Is that fine?

Possibly, possibly not.  Use [SDL_SetMainReady()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady) instead to be sure:

> `SDL_SetMainReady`: Use this function to circumvent failure of `SDL_Init()` **when not using SDL_main() as an entry point**.

Comment: After rooting around the docs to figure out how I missed SDL_SetMainReady, I found this comment on the [Initialization Category page](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryInit): "It should be noted that on some operating systems, SDL_Init() will fail if SDL_main() has not been defined as the entry point for the program. Calling SDL_SetMainReady() prior to SDL_Init() will circumvent this failure condition, however, users should be careful when calling SDL_SetMainReady() as improper initialization may cause crashes and hard to diagnose problems." so it looks like its use disables error handling...