# Using SDL2 and Creating a Reusable "Engine" for Many Other Projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl, sdl-2

I'm not sure the term for what SDL2 is doing, but I was reading that it "hijacks" main.

I have a project called `CoolGame` and a project which I want to be reusable across many other games I make, called `Engine`.

> Here is my engine.cpp

```
#include "engine.h"
using namespace engine;

Engine::Engine()
{
    window = NULL;
    renderer = NULL;
}

Engine::Engine(const char* title)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
}

void Engine::RenderThisFrame()
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Some of you may see where I am going. I am trying to make a nice Game Engine wrapper for sdl2. Here is my main in `coolgame`

```
#include "engine.h"
#include <iostream>
#undef main
using namespace std;
using namespace engine;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    cout << "break main." << endl;
    Engine e = Engine("title");

    e.RenderThisFrame();
    return 0;
}
```

This does not work. I also have tried `#undef` in `engine.h` and I get the same error as below.
`LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _SDL_main referenced in function _main_utf8`

When I take `SDL.h` and put it directly in `coolgame` it works as expected.

Is there anyway to stop `SDL2` from hijacking main? Or is there any way to hoist that main hijack to the `coolgame` project? If that makes any sense

For austerity here is

> engine.h

```
#ifndef ENGINE_CODE
#define ENGINE_CODE

#include "SDL.h"
#undef main
namespace engine {
    class Engine {
    public:
        Engine();
        Engine(const char* title);

        void RenderThisFrame();
    private:
        SDL_Window* window;
        SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    };
}
#endif
```

### Edit

I am using Visual Studio 2019 for my IDE if that matters, I can provide C++ build tools version if requested.

### Edit

I don't believe this question is exactly answered by another question. Here's why.

I have added `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` and removed the `#undefine main` and it still didn't work.

I then moved all my engine code into the `coolgame` project with `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` and main running as expected. Lo and behold it works, it has something to do with the projects being referenced. So this does not fix my original question. I am adding a Visual Studio tag.[image: these are all errors.]
I have added the engine folder to the include directories in `coolgame` and I have also added `packages/.../sdl` to the include directories

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm using the SDL functions without the SDL\_main be defined. Is that fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079288/im-using-the-sdl-functions-without-the-sdl-main-be-defined-is-that-fine)

Comment: This may help as well: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady

Comment: I have tried both solutions, and they did not seem to help. I am getting the same error. @RetiredNinja

Comment: If you `#undef main` you shouldn't link with `SDL2main`. Fix one of these.

Comment: @keltar I have removed the undef, in order to test this all, I moved everything to one project in visual studio and got the code running with `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` i think the problem is actually the way I am linking projects together in visual studio. the `Engine` project can no longer find sdl2. and yes sdl2 is referenced in the engine project. I have decided to move on for now.

Comment: SDL2 and SDL2main are separate libraries. "unresolved _SDL_main" caused by linking `SDL2main`, which only handles replaced `main` function. If you want your own main - you don't link `SDL2main` (and define `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` or undef main). Basically you informed SDL2 "hey I have my own main, please don't replace it with SDL_main", but you still link with `SDL2main`, which expects `SDL_main`, which isn't there.

Comment: @keltar I'm not sure how I can unlink SDL2main in Visual Studio.

Comment: @christopherclark isn't it in your project settings in "linker/input/additional dependencies"? How did you initially addeed SDL2 there?

Comment: @keltar it is added as a nuget package. Visual studio is doing some magic and appears to take care of all that.