# VS auto-linking against SDL2 libraries installed with vcpkg on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl, sdl-2, vcpkg

*To the best of my knowledge, this isn't a duplicate of an existing question. This question is specifically about Visual Studio's auto-linking SDL2 libraries.*

I've installed SDL2 (`x64-windows` variant) with [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg):

```
vcpkg install sdl2 --triplet x64-windows
```

And I've made vpkg libraries available to Visual Studio:

```
vcpkg integrate install
```

My VS 2019 project is configured to use the `Console` subsystem, and my main program looks like that:

```cpp
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int, char*[])
{
}
```

**Why do I need to specify `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED`? It seems that auto-linking with `SDLmain2.lib` doesn't happen for some reason?**

If I don't specify `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED`, linking fails:

```
unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
```

I've also tried adding `extern "C"` on `main()` declaration but to no avail.

I've written many apps with SDL2 but this is the first time I'm using vcpkg to locate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm using the SDL functions without the SDL\_main be defined. Is that fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079288/im-using-the-sdl-functions-without-the-sdl-main-be-defined-is-that-fine)

Comment: Hi @S.M., I'm aware of this post and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It answers the question "Why do I need to specify SDL_MAIN_HANDLED?", does not it?

Comment: It does but in a different context. I know exactly what `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` does and what it's for; what I can't figure out is why I need to use it in that specific context, and whether there's a better way to do things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a deliberate decision made by those who created the package.

If you look at [the package description file](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/ports/sdl2/portfile.cmake#L69), you can see that `SDL2main.lib` is being moved into the `manual-link` directory. I'm not familiar with `vcpkg`, so I don't know how exactly you can "manually link" against it, but I assume it's possible.

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful! Will have to figure out how to manually link that lib then.

Comment: This helped: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/12474

Answer (score 7):

### Linking SDL2 manual-link libraries while using vcpkg with VS

My answer is a follow-up to @HolyBlackCat, thanks for help.

In your case, the directory is `x64-windows`, by default it is `x86-windows`.

`Right-click on your project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties`

---

### First step

Go to: `VC++ Directories -> Library Directories`

For `Debug` configuration, add:

```
$(VCPKG_ROOT)\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\manual-link
```

For `Release` configuration, add:

```
$(VCPKG_ROOT)\installed\x64-windows\lib\manual-link
```

---

### Second step

Go to: `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`

For `Debug` configuration, add:

```
SDL2maind.lib
```

For `Release` configuration, add:

```
SDL2main.lib
```

---

Now you should not be bother by "main() redefinition" errors.