# How do I use SDL2 in my programs correctly?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

> I want to make a game using SDL2, but I'm unable to compile and/or run my code, please help!

SDL2 is notoriously hard to set up, and it's often the first library aspiring game developers try to use.

This post is intended as a canonical duplicate for common problems with setting up SDL2.

Comment: The merit of this question is involved in [a discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402771/11047824).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This answer is about MinGW / GCC, and not Visual Studio.

This answer only applies to Windows.

---

#### Common errors

The common errors are:

- `SDL.h: No such file or directory` (when compiling)
- Various `SDL_main` problems: "undefined reference to SDL_main", "conflicting types for SDL_main" or "number of arguments doesn't match prototype", etc. (when compiling or linking)
- `undefined reference` to other functions (when linking)
- DLL problems: (when running your program)

  - `'??.dll' was not found`
  - `procedure entry point ... could not be located in ...`, and other mysterious DLL-related errors
  - The program seemingly doing nothing when launched

This list is sorted from bad to good. If you change something and get a different error, use this list to tell if you made things better or worse.

---

#### The preamble

**0. Don't follow bad advice.**

Some resources will suggest you to do `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` or `#undef main`. Don't blindly follow that advice, it's not how SDL2 is intended to be used.

If you do everything correcty, it will never be necessary. Learn the intended approach first. Then you can research what exactly that does, and make an educated decision.

**1. Figure out how to compile directly from the console, you can start using an IDE and/or build system later.**
If you're using an IDE, I suggest to first make sure you're able to compile your program directly from the console, to rule out any IDE configuration problems. After you figure that out, you can use the same compiler options in your IDE.

The same applies to build systems, such as CMake.

**2. Download the right SDL2 files**. Make sure you have the right files. You need the archive called `SDL2-devel-2.0.x-mingw.tar.gz` from [here](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php).

Extract it to any directory, preferably somewhere near your source code. Extracting into the compiler installation directory is often considered a bad practice (and so is copying them to `C:\Windows`, which is a horrible idea).

**3. Know the difference between *compiler flags* and *linker flags*.** A "flag" is an option you specify in the command line when building your program. When you use a single command, e.g. `g++ foo.cpp -o foo.exe`, all your flags are added to the same place (to this single command).

But when you build your program in two steps, e.g.:

- `g++ foo.cpp -c -o foo.o` (compiling)
- `g++ foo.o -o foo.exe` (linking)

you have to know which of the two commands to add a flag to. Those are "compiler flags" and "linker flags" respectively.

Most IDEs will require you to specify compiler and linker flags separately, so even if you use a single command *now*, it's good to know which flag goes where.

Unless specified otherwise, the order of the flags doesn't matter.

---

## `SDL.h: No such file or directory`

Or any similar error related to including `SDL.h` or `SDL2/SDL.h`.

You need to tell your compiler where to look for `SDL.h`. It's in the SDL files you've downloaded (see preamble).

Add `-Ipath` to your compiler flags, where `path` is the directory where `SDL.h` is located.

Example: `-IC:/Users/HolyBlackCat/Downloads/SDL2-2.0.12/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2`. Relative paths work too, e.g. `-ISDL2-2.0.12/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2`.

Note that the path will be different depending on how you write the `#include`:

- If you do `#include <SDL.h>`, then the path should end with `.../include/SDL2` (like above). This is the recommended way.
- If you do `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`, then the path should end with `.../include`.

Note: SDL2_image (and probably other SDL addons) uses `#include "SDL.h"` in its headers. So you must either use the former option, or copy SDL2_image's `include` directory on top of SDL2's `include` directory to have `SDL_image.h` in the same directory as `SDL.h`.

---

## Various `SDL_main` problems

You can get several different errors mentioning `SDL_main`, such as `undefined reference to SDL_main`, or `conflicting types for 'SDL_main'`, or `number of arguments doesn't match prototype`, etc.

You need to have a `main` function. Your `main` function must look like `int main(int, char **)`. **NOT** `int main()` and **NOT** `void main()`. This is a quirk of SDL2, related to it doing `#define main SDL_main`.

Adding parameter names is allowed (and is mandatory in C), e.g. `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. Also the second parameter can be written as `char *[]` or with a name: `char *argv[]`. No other changes are allowed.

If your project has multiple source files, make sure to include `SDL.h` in the file that defines the `main` function, even if it doesn't otherwise use SDL directly.

Remove `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` and `#undef main` if you have them, see preamble for explanation.

---

## `undefined reference to` various functions

#### • `undefined reference to SDL_...`

The error message will mention various `SDL_...` functions, and/or `WinMain`. If it mentions `SDL_main`, consult the section "Various `SDL_main` problems" above. If the function names don't start with `SDL_`, consult the section "undefined reference to other functions" below.

You need to add following linker flags: `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -Lpath`, where `path` is the directory where `libSDL2.dll.a` and `libSDL2main.a` (which you've downloaded) are located. **The order of the `-l...` flags matters. They must appear AFTER any `.c`/`.cpp`/`.o` files.**

Example: `-LC:/Users/HolyBlackCat/Desktop/SDL2-2.0.12/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib`. Relative paths work too, e.g. `-LSDL2-2.0.12/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib`.

When you use `-l???`, the linker will look for a file called `lib???.dll.a` or `lib???.a` (and some other variants), which is why we need to pass the location of those files. `libmingw32.a` (corresponding to `-lmingw32`) is shipped with your compiler, so it already knows where to find it.

**I added all those flags and nothing changed, *or* I'm getting `skipping incompatible X when searching for Y`:**

You probably use the wrong SDL `.a` files. The archive you downloaded contains two sets of files: `i686-w64-mingw32` (32-bit) and `x86_64-w64-mingw32` (64-bit). You must use the files matching your compiler, which can also be either 32-bit or 64-bit.

Print `(8*sizeof(void*))` to see if your compiler is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Even if you think you use the right files, try the other ones to be sure.

Some MinGW versions can be switched between 32-bit and 64-bit modes using `-m32` and `-m64` flags (add them to both compiler and linker flags).

**I get `undefined reference` to a specific function:**

#### • `undefined reference to WinMain` only

There are several possibilities, all of which were covered in the previous section:

- You forgot `-lmingw32` and/or `-lSDL2main` linker flags.
  You must use following linker flags, in this exact order, **after**
  any `.c`/`.cpp`/`.o` files: `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`
- The `libSDL2main.a` file you use doesn't match your compiler (32-bit file with a 64-bit compiler, or vice versa).

Try to avoid `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` or `#undef main` when solving this issue, see preamble for explanation.

#### • `undefined reference to SDL_main` only

See the section "Various `SDL_main` problems" above.

#### • `undefined reference` to other functions

Your linker found and used `libSDL2.a`, but it should be finding and using `libSDL2.dll.a`. When both are available, it prefers the latter by default, meaning you didn't copy the latter to the directory you passed to `-L`.

If you intended to perform static linking, see the section called "How do I distribute my app to others?" below.

---

## Nothing happens when I try run my app

Let's say you try to run your app, and nothing happens. Even if you try to print something at the beginning of `main()`, it's not printed.

Windows has a nasty habit of not showing some DLL-related errors when the program is started from the console.

If you were running your app from the console (or from an IDE), instead try double-clicking the EXE in the explorer. Most probably you'll now see some DLL-related error; then consult one of the next sections.

---

## `??.dll` was not found

Copy the `.dll` mentioned in the error message, and place it next to your `.exe`.

If the DLL is called `SDL2.dll`, then it's in the SDL files you've downloaded (see preamble). Be aware that there are two different `SDL2.dll`s: a 32-bit one (in the `i686-w64-mingw32` directory), and a 64-bit one (in `x86_64-w64-mingw32`). Get the right one, if necessary try both.

Any other DLLs will be in your compiler's `bin` directory (the directory where `gcc.exe` is located).

You might need to repeat this process 3-4 times, this is normal.

For an automatic way of determining the needed DLLs, see the next section.

---

## `procedure entry point ... could not be located in ...` and other cryptic DLL errors

Your program needs several `.dll`s to run, and it found a wrong version of one, left over from some other program you have installed.

It looks for DLLs in several different places, but the directory with the `.exe` has the most priority.

You should copy all DLLs your program uses (except the system ones) into the directory where your `.exe` is located.

A reliable way to get a list of needed DLLs is to blindly copy a bunch of DLLs, and then remove the ones that turn out to be unnecessary:

- Copy `SDL2.dll`. It's in the SDL files you've downloaded (see preamble). Be aware that there are two different `SDL2.dll`s: a 32-bit one (in the `i686-w64-mingw32` directory), and a 64-bit one (in `x86_64-w64-mingw32`). Get the right one, if necessary try both.
- Copy all DLLs from your compiler's `bin` directory (the directory where `gcc.exe` is located).
- Now your program should run, but we're not done yet.
- Download [NTLDD](https://github.com/LRN/ntldd/releases) (or some other program that displays a list of used DLLs). Run `ntldd -R your_program.exe`.
- Any DLL **not** mentioned in its output should be removed from the current directory. Your program uses everything that remains.

I ended up with following DLLs, expect something similar: `SDL2.dll`, `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll` (C++ only), `libwinpthread-1.dll`.

**Can I determine the needed DLLs without copying excessive ones?**

Yes, but it's less reliable.

Your program searches for DLLs in following locations, in this order:

- The directory where your `.exe` is located.
- `C:\Windows`, including some of its subdirectories.
- The directories listed in [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

Assuming you (or some jank installer) didn't put any custom DLLs into `C:\Windows`, adding your compiler's `bin` directory to the PATH (preferably as the first entry) and either putting `SDL2.dll` in the same directory as the `.exe` or into some directory in the PATH should be enough for your program to work.

If this works, you can then run `ntldd` without copying any DLLs beforehand, and copy only the necessary ones. The reason why you'd want to copy them at all at this point (since your app already works) is to be able to distribute it to others, without them having to install the compiler for its DLLs. Skip any DLLs located outside of your compiler's `bin` directory (except for `SDL2.dll`).

Note that the possibility of having weird DLLs in `C:\Windows` is real. E.g. Wine tends to put `OpenAL32.dll` into `C:\Windows`, so if you try this process with OpenAL on Wine, it *will* fail. If you're making a sciprt that runs `ntldd` automatically, prefer copying the DLLs (or at least symlinking them - I heard MSYS2 can emulate symlinks on Windows?).

**Can I make an EXE that doesn't depend on any DLLs?**

It's possible to make an `.exe` that doesn't depend on any (non-system) `.dll`s by using the `-static` linker flag, this is called "static linking". This is rarely done, and you shouldn't need to do this if you did the above steps correctly. This requires some additional linker flags; they are listed in file `??-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig/sdl2.pc` shipped with SDL, in the `Libs.private` section. Notice that there are two files, for x32 and x64 respectively.

---

## How do I distribute my app to others?

Follow the steps in the previous section, titled `procedure entry point ... could not be located in ...`.

---

### A saner alternative?

There is [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075).

It has a package manager that lets you download prebuilt libraries, and, as a bonus, a fresh version of the compiler.

Install SDL2 from its package manager. Use a tool called `pkg-config` (also from the package manager) to automatically determine all necessary flags (`pkg-config --cflags SDL2` for compiler flags, `pkg-config --libs SDL2` for linker flags).

This is the same experience as you would have on Linux (maybe except for some DLL management hassle).

---

### Bonus - Other problems

- Q: My **program always opens a console window** when I run it, how do I hide it?

  - A: Add `-mwindows` to the linker flags.
- Q: I get **error `'SDL_VideoMode' wasn't declared in this scope`**.

  - A: `SDL_VideoMode` is from SDL1.2, it's not a part of the newer SDL2. Your code was written for the outdated version of SDL. Find a better tutorial that deals specifically with SDL2.
- Q: My **program has the default file icon**, but I want a custom one.

  - A: Your icon must be in the `.ico` format. If your graphics editor doesn't support it, make a series of `.png`s of common sizes (e.g. 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64), then convert them to a single `.ico` using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/): `magick *.png result.ico` (or with `convert` instead of `magick`).

    Create a file with the `.rc` extension (say, `icon.rc`), with following contents `MyIconName ICON "icon.ico"` (where `MyIconName` is an arbitrary name, and `"icon.ico"` is the path to the icon). Convert the file to an `.o` using `windres -O res -i icon.rc -o icon.o` (the `windres` program is shipped with your compiler). Specify the resulting `.o` file when linking, e.g. `g++ foo.cpp icon.o -o foo.exe`.

    Recent versions of SDL2 have a nice property of using the same icon as the window icon, so you don't have to use `SDL_SetWindowIcon`.

Comment: Well, times changed. You can also use Microsoft's own package manager, that also works on Linux and MacOs, and compile SDL (or almost any important package). the thing is called vcpkg and is open source. [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg#vcpkg-overview)

Comment: @arfneto I wonder if it's worth using with MinGW. Seems to be targeted primarily at MSVC, and we already have MSYS2 that deals specifically with MinGW.

Comment: HolyBlackCat you are right. It is great under Visual Studio or CMake since it downloads the sources and compiles everything with no user intervention and even sets includes and linking. Once installed you just need to include the headers on new projects. It works on Linux or Mac but I had no need for it yet so I can not say much.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for detailed explanation, it is one of the best witch I have read last 5 years. It absolutely solve all my troubles.

Answer (score 2):

**A solution for Visual Studio:**

Why not use a package manager? I use [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg), and it makes super easy to consume 3rd party libraries. Grab the vcpkg source, and extract it to a safe place, like `C:/`, then run its bootstrap script `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`, this will generate `vcpkg` executable. Then run `vcpkg integrate install` to make libraries installed with vcpkg available in Visual Studio.

Search for the library you need:

```
vcpkg search sdl

imgui[sdl2-binding]                   Make available SDL2 binding
libwebp[vwebp-sdl]                    Build the vwebp viewer tool.
magnum[sdl2application]               Sdl2Application library
sdl1                 1.2.15#12        Simple DirectMedia Layer is a cross-platform development library designed to p...
sdl1-net             1.2.8-3          Networking library for SDL
sdl2                 2.0.12-1         Simple DirectMedia Layer is a cross-platform 
...
```

Install it with: `vcpkg install sdl2`.

Now you just need include SDL2 headers, and everything will work out of the box. The library will be linked automatically.

You can learn more about vcpkg [here](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: You're missing one step: you have to manually link SDL2main (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64079180/2752075)), or use some workaround to avoid it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just tried and it seems more like a SDL thing to me. If you add `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` before including SDL headers it works fine and no need to manually link anything.

Comment: See preamble, part 0 in my long answer above. The recommended (by SDL developers) solution is to link `SDL2main`. `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` also works, but it's not recommended. It's a different question whether the recommended way is reasonable, and some people think it's not (apparently that includes vcpkg packagers).

Answer (score 1):

On Mac this is what I follow for XCode (must install g++):

**sdl linking:**

```
g++ main.cpp -o main $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs)
```

**XCODE project steps:**

1. open terminal app (macOS)
2. BUILD SETTINGS (select 'all' and 'combined' search bar enter: "search")
3. click on "header search paths(way right side click)
4. add: `/usr/local/include`
5. BUILD PHASES --> LINK BINARY LIBRARIES (click plus)
6. type in `SDL` --> click "add other"
7. press: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> (to bring search bar)
8. type in: `usr/local/Cellar`
9. navigate to: SDL2 -->2.0.8 -->lib --> libSDL2-2.2.0.dylib (make sure not shortcut)