# How to successfully compile an SDL2 C program with MinGW

Tags: c, mingw, sdl-2

I am trying to compile a basic SDL2 program in C.
This program worked fine on my Artix laptop, where I can simply install the library with pacman and have that be the end of it. but as I'm trying to "port" it to windows, I cannot compile it at all.
I tried using the runtime binary (.dll) form the SDL2 website, but all internet results on how to use it were completely incomprehensible.
So, I then tried downloading the folder of headers and including them with `#include "SDL2/SDL.h"`.
When I run `gcc main.c`, I get undefined references to every `SDL_SomeFunction` function. I have tried adding various options to the compiler like `-lSDL2` or setting `-IC:/path/to/stuff`, with no luck.
So, what am I missing here?
More importantly, what is the recommended way to do this on Windows? Should I have a completely different approach?

Comment: -> [How do I use SDL2 in my programs correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396979/how-do-i-use-sdl2-in-my-programs-correctly)

Comment: ^ The linked thread should everything you need. If not, ask.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I actually saw that thread while searching because I figured my issue wasn't too special. Upon closer reading of the thread, I added some linker flags `gcc -o app .\main.c -lmingw32 -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -mwindows -LC:.\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\` and got a lot less errors, although it still doesn't compile due to missing definitions.

Comment: Your flag order is wrong. I believe that post mentions that order matters.