# Using SDL2 with cpp

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Im using gcc 8.1.0 compiler, to compile my cpp code to start using SDL2. However when running the test code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "hello workd" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And to run it im using this cmd.
`gcc -o main main.cpp -Isrc/include -Lsrc/lib -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lstdc++ -std=c++11 -m64`

And i get this error: `C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to 'WinMain'      collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

If i add -municode tag, it gives this: `C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_w.o):crt0_w.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to wWinMain' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Currently Following this tutorial: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H08t6gD1Y1E&list=LL&index=1&t=120s&ab_channel=HerbGlitch`

My folder structure:

project file has [src,main.cpp,SDL2.dll]

'src' folder has 'include' and 'lib' from SDL2 mingw development library.

EDI: When I tried using -lmingw64 it gives  `cannot find -lmingw64  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I also tried ctrl+s to properly save the file before compiling, nothing worked.

EDIT:
MY SOLUTION:
I was trying to do everything with 64 bit compiler and files, couldn't solve the problem as I was stuck on the error produced by -lmingw64 flag.

I Uninstalled the 64 bit compiler and replaced it with 32 bit compiler and replaced all files with 32 bit version, and it worked using -lmingw32 flag.

I guess, I didn't install the 64 bit compiler properly/didn't add something important to path, as I added all the path variables manually.

Comment: If you search for e.g. `sdl2 undefined reference to 'WinMain'` in your favorite search engine, what kind of result do you get?

Comment: Also note that `gcc` is usually use for C programs, while `g++` is used for C++ programs.

Comment: I tried the solutions mentioned, nothing worked. But a post saying I am missing the 'WinMain' function in my program seemed to make some sense, but I don't understand how to rectify the mistake. Also when i'm using gcc i also make sure to give -lstdc++, which i guess is equivalent to g++.

Comment: See section "undefined reference to WinMain only" in the linked thread.

Comment: This answer should help: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396980/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396980/487892)

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong binaries for your compiler.

Comment: I guess the first main problem will be to solve the unable to use -lmingw64 command, and i couldnt find a solution for this.

Comment: The link explains everything you need to know. You don't need `-lmingw64`.

Comment: So, i guess the 64 bit compiler had a problem/i installed it improperly. Only 32bit version works on this computer. So the problem was indeed in the -lmingw32 flag. Edited the question with my solution. Thanks for your helps :)

Comment: You're welcome. :) Even a 64-bit compiler would need `-lmingw32`, there's no `-lmingw64`.