# error : undefined reference to winmain sur codeblocks /(sdl install)

Tags: sdl, codeblocks, winmain

To install SDL2 with codeblocks , i recieve when i compile the error : "undefined reference to winmain "
I added -L mingw32 -L SDL2 -L SDL2main
-mwindows

but still the same problem
anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use SDL2 in my programs correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396979/how-do-i-use-sdl2-in-my-programs-correctly)

Comment: In particular, you need `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2` (in this order, with lowercase L's). `-mwindows` is unrelated, it just hides the terminal window.