# DLL Error Following the tutorial for gtkmm

Tags: c++, mingw, gtkmm, msys2

I'm following the gtkmm tutorial for gtkmm4 and I'm getting an odd error when I try to run my program. The program is an exact copy of the provided code, and it compiles successfully:
[image]

However, when I run the program it gives me a series of errors:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm not sure what to do at this point. I've tried googling, but I don't get anything helpful. I've check that the DLL in question does exist. Any advice is appreciated!

Edit: I ran the Dependency Walker program, and got some errors, not sure what this means though.

[image]

Edit2: I did some research on Dependency Walker, and it seems to have some known issues, so I also ran [lucasg's "Dependencys" program](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), with this output. I'm still not really sure what this means, but it seems fine.

[image]

Edit3: I moved the 4 offending dll files into the build directory, and these are the new errors I'm getting. Its the same error, but now it points to the more local file.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: See the section on DLL debugging [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396980/2752075). That's for a different library, but should apply here too.

Comment: Did you manually modify MSYS2 installation in any way, except for `pacman`? Did you run `make install` for any libraries?

Comment: If you didn't, are you using MSYS2 with the default PATH, or you've configured it to inherit system PATH? If you do inherit (or modify) PATH, stop doing that. If you don't, check if any DLLs in `/mingw64/bin` also exist in `C:\Windows` (including subdirectories). If you find any overlaps, delete them from the latter location.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the DLL debugging section! Based on that, It sounds like the DLLs are somehow wrong? I tried to copy the DLLS from my MSYS mingw64 folder into the build folder, but it didn't help. It did change the error message to have the new DLL location though, so I think I copied the files correctly. 

As for your questions, I only used pacman  (no make install), I haven't messed with the PATH, and I didn't find any DLLS in the C:\Windows folder. Is there anything else I should try to get more information?

Comment: Most of the problems described in that post shouldn't happen in MSYS2. So how exactly did you install gtkmm and other libraries?

Comment: I followed the tutorial [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/MSWindows) and installed everything using pacman. As to how I installed MSYS2, it was so long ago I can't say. Might it be worth a fill reinstall of MSYS2?

Comment: One thing to note I guess is that I did install both gtkmm 3 and 4. Perhaps that could be causing issues? I'll try to uninstall gtkmm 3 and see if that fixes anything

Comment: Ah. I didn't notice that you were running your program **outside** of MSYS2. Yes, you're supposed to copy those DLLs. Please show the new errors you got.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've added the images to the post. Its the same error, but it points to the more local file now.

Comment: Please read the link in my first comment again. It explains what DLLs to copy. Start reading from "For ntldd algorithm is".

Comment: Oh wow yeah that did it! I missed the part where I had to copy ALL the DLLs, not just the ones that were erroring

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the help! If you post an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: You're welcome! I don't think I'm going to post one, since I already have that answer I linked... You can post one yourself though, if you want to.

Comment: Understandable, I'll do that just in case anyone else has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `.exe` file with [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see which issues there are loading the `.dll` files.

One possible cause could be that you're mixing 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that! I ran the program, but I'm not really sure what its telling me. Clearly, something is wrong though. I made an edit with the output, does it tell you anything?

Comment: It clearly says you're mixing CPUs, meaning you're mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: How do I fix that? I was able to get it to work by copying DLLS from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin into the build directory, but I'm not sure why it wasn't able to find the correct DLLS on its own in the first place. Is there a compiler flag I should be setting here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was something to do with finding the correct DLLs. The solution, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396979/how-do-i-use-sdl2-in-my-programs-correctly/64396980#64396980), is to copy **all** the DLLs from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin into the build directory. Then, using ntldd or some other profiler, determine which DLLs are unnecessary and remove them.

Comment: The `copypedeps -r` command from https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps can be used to copy only those `.dll` files that are used by your `.exe` (or `.dll`) file(s).