# MinGW undefined reference libcurl

Tags: c++, mingw, libcurl

So i have written an app in c++ to download mp3s from the web using a list.
It uses libcurl to download them.

I am on linux. Compiling with

```
 g++ main.cpp -lcurl -o word2mp3
```

works fine.
I need an windows executable, but running
`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -o wordtest` returns the

```
undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_init'
```

followed by the other curl functions. Adding -lcurl to the command also gives an error saying that curl isn't found.

I've tried and searched everywhere, no luck, I'm a beginner.

Link to my github repo: https://github.com/sharpclone/Word2Mp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile libcurl with MinGW, or find a precompiled one. The one you installed to compile your app on Linux was compiled with a Linux compiler, and wouldn't work with MinGW.

[MSYS2 repos](https://repo.msys2.org/mingw/mingw64/) have a bunch of precompiled libraries for different flavors of MinGW.

I've made [a script](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2) to automatically download those libraries, since their package manager only works on Windows.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/holyblackcat/quasi-msys2
cd quasi-msys2
make install _gcc _curl
env/shell.sh

cd ..
git clone https://github.com/sharpclone/Word2Mp3
cd Word2Mp3/
win-clang++ main.cpp -lcurl -o word2mp3
```

This doesn't rely on an external MinGW installation, and only requires Clang (and LLD) to be installed (a regular Clang for Linux, unlike GCC you don't need to install a special version of it to cross-compile).

Or, if you prefer your existing compiler, you can stop at `make install _curl`, then manually specify the path to the installed library, normally `-Lquasi-msys2/root/mingw64/lib`. You just need to make sure the [MSYS2 repo you're using](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2#not-so-frequently-asked-questions=) matches your compiler.

Comment: I think i'm stupid , Im on arch , i used pacman -S clang. I Followed and isntalled the _gcc and _curl, now it says that theres no such command win-clang++, simply clang works. MinGW just refuses to do something

Comment: You need to do `env/shell.sh` first. It opens a shell where `win-clang++` is added to the PATH.

Comment: Ok another error code: `/home/mihai/gits/quasi-msys2/env/wrappers/win-clang++: line 2: : command not found
` The file content: `#!/bin/sh
"$WIN_NATIVE_CLANG_CXX" $WIN_CLANG_FLAGS "$@"
`

Comment: @MihaiCazac Did you run `env/shell.sh`, or did you manually specify full path to `win-clang++`? If `env/shell.sh` doesn't help (which is weird), try doing `export WIN_NATIVE_CLANG_CXX=clang++`...

Comment: OK finally it worked now , one last caveat that running it in windows returns this app can't run on your pc, yes i run env/shell

Comment: @MihaiCazac I have a strong suspicion that you're not running `env/shell.sh`, and end up producing a Linux executable instead of a Windows one ("can't run on your pc" supports that). Can you explain in detail what commands you used?

Comment: The image: [https://imgur.com/a/AGdVMLE](https://imgur.com/a/AGdVMLE) _italic_ **bold**. My exact steps: After make install  i exported that win native then i followed the exact steps: `[mihai@mihai-arch quasi-msys2]$ cd ..
[mihai@mihai-arch gits]$ cd Word2Mp3/
[mihai@mihai-arch Word2Mp3]$ win-clang++ main.cpp -lcurl -o word2mp3v3.exe
`

Comment: Also can you share the output from `env/shell.sh`?

Comment: Note i did it all in env/shell.sh . `--- binfmt.mk
`binfmt_misc` mounted? YES
`binfmt_misc` enabled? YES
Executable format registered? YES
Executable format enabled? YES

--- fakebin.mk
Makefile:167: *** Aborted.  Stop.
Nothing to do.

--- vars.sh
The environment variables are already set.
Restart the shell and re-run this script to update them.
`

Comment: @MihaiCazac Close the terminal, open a new one, run `env/shell.sh` again and show what it prints. Don't do `export WIN_NATIVE_CLANG_CXX`, just try running `win-clang++ ...` in it again.

Comment: Guessing a compiler... To override, set `MINGW_CC` and `MINGW_CXX` and restart.
Trying native Clang...
  Guessed Clang version suffix: WIN_CLANG_VER = 13
  You can override it by setting it to a number or to `NONE` for no suffix.
which: no clang++-13 in (/home/mihai/.emacs.d/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-j9//bin:/snap/bin)
Fail.
Trying MSYS2 Clang... (not recommended)
Fail.
Trying MSYS2 GCC...
Success.
CC  = gcc
CXX = g++

Comment: When running win-clang++ = command not found

Comment: It seems that it defaults the CC to gcc and Cxx to g++, the msys2 Clang fails

Comment: @MihaiCazac For some reason you have `clang-13` installed but not `clang++-13`, which is weird (and messes up compiler detection). Restart the terminal, run `export WIN_CLANG_VER=NONE`, then run `env/shell.sh` and try `win-clang++` again.

Comment: I've fixed the script to handle this automatically, even though I'm not sure why it's needed.

Comment: Wait theres more).It never ends. Now i get invalid linker name in argument : '-fuse-ld=lld"

Comment: @MihaiCazac You need to install `lld`, as the readme says. :)

Comment: The link to everything used (pastebin) [https://pastebin.com/atTpJX50](https://pastebin.com/atTpJX50) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: Finally, thanks it worked , i still get some errors on windows like libstdc++ not found but i think i tortured you enough ,Thanks! :)

Comment: @MihaiCazac No problem. You need to copy those dlls from `quasi-msys2/mingw64/root/mingw64/bin/` and place them next to your executable. Also see the section on the DLL debugging [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396980/2752075) (that's for a different library, but should work equally well here too).

Answer (score 1):

To fix the undefined reference warning, you need to link to the required library, so the `-lcurl` is correct and required.

If the compiler cannot find the library, you need to tell him where to find it, that can be done by passing `-L` followed by the path to the library (that would be the path to the directory where `libcurl.dll.a` is in).

The order of the parameters can also be relevant, I think the correct order would be `-L <path> -lcurl`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the problem is still the same...I tried to spun up a windows vm and after installing libcurl it's the same problem. The code i used: `.\g++.exe C:\Users\Mihai\Desktop\Word2Mp3-main\main.cpp -o C:\Users\Mihai\Desktop\Word2Mp3-main\word2mp3 -LC:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\curl\tools\curl-7.82.0-win64-mingw\lib -lcurl`