# SDL Image "undefined reference to `IMG_LoadTexture`

Tags: c++, sdl, undefined-reference, sdl-image

I've got the following piece of code attempting to use SDL_image;

```
#include <iostream>
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

int WIDTH = 800;
int HEIGHT = 800;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) > 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL INIT FAILED" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Chaturanga", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
    
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    if (NULL == window)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not create window: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Texture* boardTexture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "res/images/board.png");

    if (boardTexture == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture. Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    SDL_Event windowEvent;

    while (true)
    {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
        {
            if (SDL_QUIT == windowEvent.type)
            {break;}
        }
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, boardTexture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I compile with:

```
g++ src/*.cpp -o main.exe -I lib/SDL2_lib/include -L lib/sdl2_lib/libr -L lib/sdl2_lib -lsdl2 -lsdl2_image
```

I get the following error;
[image: Error Image]

My file structure is as follows, all functionality not relating to sdl image works fine.

[image]

Yes, the sdl_image.h file is in include;
Inside the libr folder:

[image]

Comment: Probably a wrong `libSDL2_image[.dll].a`? An x32 one with an x64 compiler, or vice versa. Also an obligatory reminder that `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` is a hack and shouldn't bee necessary, see [How do I use SDL2 in my programs correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64396979/2752075).

Comment: Yep, you were right, can you create an actual answer so I can flag you as right

Comment: I can't, because the question is already closed. But I don't need to, because I've already made a comprehensive guide on this, which I've added to the questions your is closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: It was more if you wanted rep but thanks anyways