# Cross-compiling c++ with sdl on linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sdl, cross-compiling

I'm on Arch Linux, and I have a C++ SDL2 program, contained in single `main.cpp` file, and I compile it for Linux with such command:

```
g++ main.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

Now I wanna compile it for windows. Any advice on what should I do?

Comment: Mingw is what you want

Comment: I know, but I need to do some weird importing, and downloading thingies, that I don't know how.

Comment: You may want to look into [CMake](https://cmake.org) and [Conan](https://conan.io) to have a decent system of handling building and dependencies cross UNIX-like platforms and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest my own tool, [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2), which lets you reuse the precompiled SDL2 for MinGW provided by [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) (and more).

Install Clang, LLD, `make`, `wget`, `tar`, `zstd`, `gpg`.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2
cd quasi-msys2/
make install _gcc _SDL2 _SDL2_image
env/shell.sh
win-clang++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2 SDL2_image`
```

This should produce `a.exe`, which you can test using `wine a.exe` (or just `./a.exe`, after running `env/shell.sh`).

---

**How to do this manually:**

For completeness, SDL2 itself distributes precompiled binaries for MinGW, meaning the manual setup is not hard. Any tutorial for MinGW should work.

Install MinGW from your package manager.

Download and unpack [`SDL2-devel-??-mingw.zip`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/latest) and [`SDL2_image-devel-??-mingw.zip`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image/releases/latest).

Specify the paths to the directories with `.a` files using `-L...` and to `.h` files using `-I...`. Add `-lmingw32 -lmingw32 -mwindows -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image` to the linker flags.

Follow this [troubleshooting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64396979/2752075) if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for cmake really.. SDL2 ships with  a CMakeLists.txt and it's as simple as running this from your build folder.

`cmake.exe ..`

`cmake.exe --build .`

EDIT: if you want to cross-compile, you need MinGW and the addition of the mingw flags to the cmake generator

```
cmake \
  -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/path/to/wingw/gcc \
  -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/mingw/g++ \
  -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
```

Comment: Normally this would produce a native build. OP wants to cross-compile, so this requires extra flags.

Comment: I assumed access to a Windows PC. My bad