# GCC refuses to link SDL2 .a files

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker-errors, sdl-2

So, I have a command I run to compile this experiment. It looks like this.

`"F:\Software-Development\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe" "F:\Software-Development\Sources\experiment\source\main.c" -L "F:\Software-Development\Sources\experiment\objects\" -Wall -o "F:\Software-Development\Sources\experiment\~build\EXP" -lSDL2`

main.c is just a slightly modified tutorial from [Lazyfoo](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php) so that it SHOULD work in pure C, though I can't actually test it. If the actual source code is required for whatever reason, I do have a testing package I assembled [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/442648971135942657/1023161743842758736/Testing.7z). It probably won't work, but again, can't test it for errors. **Please do not inform me of potential errors in my code, unless it's actually relevant to this error.**

\objects\ is where my .a files are stored. For some inexplicable reason, however, whenever I execute this command, it throws an error. Not a `cannot find -lSDL2: No such file or directory` error, but rather an `` undefined reference to `SDL_X' `` error.

This makes no sense to me, the .a files are right there, and I'm not sure what is going on. My only clue in is that removing -L throws the `cannot find -lSDL2` error, while modifying what's in the -L parameter changes literally nothing. I've asked elsewhere for help, I've looked around at problems, and it seems that I have left but to ask Stack Overflow for something that's probably really trivial.

Comment: There is always an _explicable_ reason, and that reason is _always_ that your environment is not correctly configured.

Comment: Cool. It doesn't explain where the misconfiguration is. How about you take a look at my batch file which does this and tell me where it is? [Because I sure don't see where I'm going wrong with this.](https://pastebin.com/maCQBvHu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use SDL2 in my programs correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396979/how-do-i-use-sdl2-in-my-programs-correctly)

Comment: In particular, on Windows you need `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2` rather than just `-lSDL2`. If it still doesn't work, this means you've been using x32 libs with an x64 compiler, or vice versa.

Comment: Well, that didn't fix things at all. I added all of the flags, and changed the location of the -Ldir flag, and that gave me a new error. Particularly, "cannot find -lSDL2x:". Fixing the position of the -Ldir flag back to where it was yielded no advancements, it's still throwing the undefined errors no matter which set of .a SDL2 files I'm using(i686 or x86_64). In batch, the command now looks like this "%compiler:~0,-1%\gcc.exe" %build:~0,-1%\source\main.c" -ggdb -Wall -L "%build:~1,-1%\objects\" -o %build:~0,-1%\~build\%dat:~1,-1%" -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2".

Comment: What's `:~1,-1%`? Why does it say `-lSDL2x:` rather than `-lSDL2`? Does it work if you compile from the terminal and specify the paths manually, not using variables? If not, where did you get your GCC? The one from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) is known to work correctly.

Comment: `:~1,-1%` is the substring command for Batch(in this case, start at the 2nd letter in a string, end to the 2nd to last character in a string.) `-lSDL2x` is just a shorthand for `-lSDL2 -lSDL2main` and sometimes `-lSDL2test`, apologies that this was not clear. It does not work even when I specify manually where it's supposed to go. I got my GCC from [MinGW-w64's official website](https://www.mingw-w64.org/), specifically the latest[(Release 12.2.0-rt_v10-rev0)](https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases/tag/12.2.0-rt_v10-rev0) i686 and x86_64 sljl Win32 threading builds.

Comment: Please use `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: `-L` shouldn't change anything regarding `undefined reference` errors. Perhaps you have multiple sets of .a files, some of them not matching your compiler. Adding `-v` should print the library paths that were used.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I wish it were that easy to brush it off, but I didn't have multiple sets of the same .a files in there. This is proven by the fact that removing `-L` and just moving everything to the `lib` folder actually rectified the issue. Furthermore, I went on to count after the 5th or so retry, and I exchanged all of my .a files a whooping 92 times. The `lib` files are also the ones that were in the `object` folder from my very last test. The only conclusion I can possibly draw from this is that mingW's `gcc.exe` don't account for `-L` correctly. Atings take up valuable characters :(

Comment: Again: add `-v` to commands with and without `-L`, and compare the resulting library paths.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry, I didn't get your comment for some reason. Here's the pastebin with your requested test. https://pastebin.com/2xQ2Ngc2 I ran both. Use W/O as a ctrl+F term to find the split between the two tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've discovered the reason why. This is absolutely ridiculous, but mingw's GCC compilation does not appear to account for `-L` correctly. The only solution you can do to rectify this error is to remove the `-L` dir flag and putting the `.a` files into the `mingX\lib` folder.