# "undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'" when adding SDL2 libraries in C++ environment

Tags: c++, eclipse, sdl-2, undefined-reference, multiple-definition-error

I have been trying to get SDL2 to work in my environment but have had no luck. I am using Windows 10 Home with MinGW, working in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers.

I downloaded SDL2.26.4 from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.26.4).

After downloading and extracting the files, I copied the contents of the SDL2 include and lib files to my MinGW folder in C:\MinGW.

In my IDE, I added the include and library paths.

[image]

[image]

I also included some recommended linker flags suggested from other solutions, but they have had no impact.

[image]

When I run the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

...I am met with errors:

```
C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\SDL2 test\Debug/../src/SDL2 test.cpp:12: multiple definition of `main'
C:\MinGW\lib/libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
C:\MinGW\lib/libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried recreating my project, putting my include and library folders in different file locations, different variations of inhibiting SDL from redefining my 'main' function, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Refer to [How do I use SDL2 in my programs correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396980/2752075).

Comment: I've followed every piece of advice offered in the link you provided and still am met with "undefined reference to `WinMain@16'". All of my linker flags are set, my include files and libraries are identified, I have experimented with using 32 and 64 bit versions of the SDL2 package, but have not made any progress.

Comment: After reviewing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16 answer provided by genpfault, I experimented by changing my main() function to WinMain(), at which point the program was able to be compiled.

Comment: Renaming it shouldn't be necessary. Did you remove `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` as the post suggests in the preamble?

Comment: Yes, I removed SDL_MAIN_HANDLED from the beginning of my script. Also, I spoke too soon earlier; while the code was able to be compiled and execute "Hello World", as soon as I started calling SDL-specific functions I was met with more "undefined reference to 'SDL_main'" errors. I have been troubleshooting this development since.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the linked guide covers everything that could go wrong (except for some really weird scenarios). Double-check that you're following everything. E.g. perhaps you experimented with x32 vs x64 libs, but the compiler was using libs located elsewhere.

Comment: I did eventually get SDL to launch in a new IDE. I changed from Eclipse to Visual Studio Code. I was using Eclipse to follow along with a guide as closely as possible, but this will have to do. Thank you for all the help!