# undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow' when setting up SDL2

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl-2

I recently wanted to start learning SDL2 and followed codergophers installation tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsG6dJlLBDw&list=PL2RPjWnJduNmXHRYwdtublIPdlqocBoLS). However I ran into this error for some reason

**(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'**

**(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'**

This is my MakeFile (in all honesty I don't fully understand a whole lot of whats going on in the MakeFile so please correct me if im making some blatant mistake)

```
all:
    g++ -Iinclude -Iinclude/SDL2 -Iinclude/headers -I C:/SDL2-w64/include -Llib -o Main src/*.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main  -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -LC:/SDL2-w64/lib
```

and my file tree is

[image]

Where SDL2 contains the header files for SDL_Image.h and SDL.h and a whole bunch more.
I also have a copy of x86_64-w64-mingw32 on my C drive under the name of SDL2-w64.

My code as for now is as follow:

**src/main.cpp**

```cpp
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "headers/RenderWindow.hpp"

int main(int argc , char* argv[]){

    RenderWindow window("Test" , 1280 , 720);

    return 0;
}
```

**src/renderwindow.cpp**

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

#include "headers/RenderWindow.hpp"
#include <iostream>

RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const char* title, int w , int h)
    :window(NULL) , renderer(NULL)
{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(title , SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED , SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED , w , h , SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if(window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Window failed to init. Error" << std::endl;
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window , -1 ,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
}
```

**include/headers/RenderWindow.hpp**

```cpp
#pragma one
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

class RenderWindow
{
public:
    RenderWindow(const char* title , int w, int h);
private:
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;

};
```

Again thank you so much for reading through all this. I spent a long time debugging this so I apologise in advance if I'm making some obvious blunder. Please feel free to ask any more follow up questions if the information provided is not necessary. Thank you :)

Comment: You probably want `-LC:/SDL2-w64/lib` before any of the attempts to libk libraries in that directory. What is the process you are using to compile this? Are you sure the makefile is being used?

Comment: Refer to [How do I use SDL2 in my programs correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396979/how-do-i-use-sdl2-in-my-programs-correctly), it has everything you need to know. Probably an x32 SDL2 with an x64 compiler or vice versa. Also note that `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` is bad and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @RetiredNinja im using the command `mingw32-make -f MakeFile` to compile this.