# Dependencies SDL when shipping out a game

Tags: c++, sdl, dynamic-linking

I'm working on a game right now with C++ using the SDL graphics library. Let's say I want to publish this game, how would I make sure my users are able to run it. From my understanding, SDL is a dynamically linked library. How will I make sure my users have the means to compile a SDL application.

I know there exist questions concerning linking but only the development phase and not necessarily packaging the application.

I've looked up how to link libraries both static and dynamically many times and haven't found much related to SDL, or how to package an application that uses dynamic instead of static. If time permits, can you also answer the question of "IF the library allows for static linking, do we include all lib files into our final package?"

Comment: If the library is statically linked you don’t need to include any extra files along with your executable. If your library is dynamically linked you need to include all the distributable library files along with your executable (.dll on windows for example).

Comment: Can you go into further details why that is so?

Comment: Statically linked means that *everything* is included in the executable. Then you just have to distribute that file (but it will also be LARGE).

Comment: *"into further details why that is so?"* That's the whole point of static vs dynamic linking.

Comment: Static linking is usually discouraged, because it prevents the user from updating the library if needed. To make it work using dynamic linking, you just need to distribute `SDL2.dll` with your executable (some other DLLs too, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64396979/2752075)).

Comment: So if they install my executable along with the SDL2.dll, they should be fine?

Comment: Please add `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications. Yes, that should be enough. You also need a few other DLLs (unrelated to SDL2).