# How to fix the procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c++, dll, sfml

while running sfml project in codeblocks , it says "the procedure entry point _zst28_throw bad array length could not be located in dynamic link library " . what to do?

I had tried to solve it watching youtube but it didn't work. i want its solution

Comment: It probably tries to search for `libstdc++-<number>.dll` (where `<number>` is dependent on which version of the toolchain you use). A quick fix would be to look for that file where you've installed your compiler and copy it into the same directory as where your `.exe` file is or where you run the program from.

Comment: Making random, multiple copies of DLLs on a Windows system is really a great piece of advice, especially for those who are learning and don't have a lot of technical experience.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Chances are pretty high that OP will need to distribute the dll(s) with his app anyway for a receiver to be able to run it if I correctly understood the matches I got when I searched for the error. Perhaps I made a mistake but even this thorough checklist mentions it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396979/how-do-i-use-sdl2-in-my-programs-correctly/64396980#64396980

Comment: Well, before getting to the distribution part, the whole thing needs to be built first, which is where the problem is. Furthermore, I'm pretty sure it's possible to distribute companion libraries without making umpteen copies of them.