# Linking SDL_Image with CMake makes my program exit immediately after being run

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2, sdl-image

So, I've setup SDL2 and SDL_Image with CMake (both on their respective `SDL2` branches), but when I add `IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG | IMG_INIT_JPG);` the program just doesn't do anything when run. Like, it doesn't even crash, it just doesn't run. The same issue happens if I link SDL2 as a shared library.

I'm on Windows 11 and I'm using [MinGW](https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases/tag/13.2.0-rt_v11-rev0) (`mingw32-make`) (downloaded today so the most recent version).

Here's my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
## Setup
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.9)
project(Pacman LANGUAGES CXX)

## SDL2
add_subdirectory("external/SDL2")

## SDL_image
add_subdirectory("external/SDL_image")

## Compile
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "src/main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2::SDL2-static SDL2_image::SDL2_image)
```

It works fine for just SDL2 (as long as I statically link it. I've got no idea why it's not working. Here's my code:

```cpp
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { // thanks, https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/06/02/using-sdl2-with-cmake/
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Pacman",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        1920,
        1080,
        0
    );

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    // this doesn't run if the IMG_Init line is uncommented
    printf("working up to here");

    // this is the troublesome line. I'm guessing that SDL_Image is only linked when functions from it are used, and something with SDL_Image breaks my program?
    // // Initialize PNG loading
    // IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG | IMG_INIT_JPG);

    SDL_Delay(3000);
    
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try static linking for `SDL2_image` too?

Comment: @ted-lyngmo How do I do that?

Comment: I can't verify it right now but I would guess by changing `SDL2_image::SDL2_image` to `SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static`.

Comment: I've tried that, CMake can't find `SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static` :(

Comment: Ok, then search for `SDL_image.dll` in your SDL installation. Copy `SDL_image.dll` to the directory where your program is. That should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried that with no luck.

Comment: What didn't work? Didn't you find `SDL_image.dll` or didn't putting a copy in the directory help?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Putting a copy in the directory didn't help.

Comment: This is 100% a missing/mismatched DLL. How do you run the program? Try double-clicking it in the explorer, this sometimes shows a better error message.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Whoa, that helped a ton! Here's the error message: "The code execution cannot proceed because SDL2.dll was not found. Reinstall the program may fix this problem."

I've just tried copying the SDL2.dll file and that works, but surely there's a better solution than that? It feels janky.

Comment: You'll have to copy the DLLs anyway to distribute your app to others, the only question is how to automate it. (And your program uses more DLLs than just `SDL2.dll`, you might have them in PATH but your users won't.) The process I follow is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396980/2752075) (start reading from "other cryptic DLL errors"). I don't know any tools that do this, so I always made my own scripts to automate this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That was a nice guide! It got me curious about looking into SDL again. I got as far as making a Pong game last time :-)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks, I'll give that guide a read later! For now, I'm just going to write a Powershell script. Thanks again! Would you like to repost as an answer so I can set it as the answer for anybody encountering the same issue?