# Including SFML library in assignment submission

Tags: makefile, sfml

I finished my assignment for a class I'm taking, and I wrote it in C++ and used SFML to animate some portions of it. To make sure that the program can actually run in the case that whoever is trying to use it doesn't have SFML installed, can I simply include the entire SFML library within my program directory? If so, how should I go about doing that? I am using a Makefile to compile my code, so I can specify where the program should look for the library.

Everything works so far, but want to ensure it will work when I submit it.

Here is my Makefile:

```
CC=g++
SFML_BASE_PATH=./sfml/2.6.1
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -I$(SFML_BASE_PATH)/include
LDFLAGS=-L$(SFML_BASE_PATH)/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
DEPS = AStar.hpp
OBJ = main.o Search.o

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)

makepancake: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o makepancake
```

Comment: This depends on whether you linked SFML statically or dynamically, do you know?

Comment: If your SFML has dlls put them in the same folder as the executable. You may also need to put dlls for your compiler's runtime. With that said your professor or TA should have described how to upload / submit your project.

Comment: The answer depends on what your TA or professor says. Perhaps it suffices to attach a note saying you need Sfml, perhaps they are okay with a conanfile or vcpkg.

Comment: I linked it dynamically

Comment: Yeah the assignment didn't require animation, but there are extra credit points if we can animate the algorithm, but it was not specified how to implement that. I can always ask, just wanted to see if I could ensure it working no matter what.

Comment: What compiler are you using? MinGW?

Comment: I'm using g++ @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396979/how-do-i-use-sdl2-in-my-programs-correctly/64396980#64396980), starting from `How do I distribute my app to others?`. (I really should make a separate Q&A about that.) In short, you need a list of DLLs your app uses (from `ntldd -R my_app.exe`, install ntldd from MSYS2), then copy them next to the exe, excluding the ones in `C:\Windows`.