# Cannot link a C file that has an easy example with SDL2

Tags: c, makefile, mingw, sdl-2, undefined-reference

I was creating images in C, and I wanted to render the .ppm images on SDL2, and I made the installation, following the steps [here](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/mingw/index.php), but I encounter problems linking just a simple test for a window, the linker cannot found the implementation, even tho the SDL2.dll is in the same directory that my .c file

I am not using a Cmake file to compile the code I'm using some commands recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396979/how-do-i-use-sdl2-in-my-programs-correctly) to compile

```
gcc testSDL.c -o jaja.exe -lmingw32 -lSDL2 -l"C:\MinGW\lib"
gcc testSDL.c -o jaja.exe -lmingw32 -lSDL2 -lC:\C_libraries\SDL2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib
```

The code is just

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("GAME",
                                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                    1000, 1000, 0);
    while (1);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried almost everything I could (even incluiding manually into the comand the path to the include files), and I'm also using some VS Code extension to compile (like Code runner), also I'm using the x64SDL library, And I'm using the MinGW to run things.

But I still get this errors:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\MinGW\lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I faced all those same errors too.  Reading the documentation and following carefully resolved them all.  I *thought* I did that already, but on the 2nd pass ( because all the errors ) I found the keys.  Some  errors I did fix on my own, but it took me sooo long I wished later I just read the docs more carefully.

Comment: You’ve forgotten to link [libSDLmain](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/mingw/index.php#3) as was mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: Probably x32 libs with x64 compiler, or vice versa.

Comment: Consider reinstalling your compiler from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075), and install SDL2 from it too. Then it's guaranteed to be compatible.

Comment: I change the command to compile and got
gcc testSDL.c -o jaja.exe -lmingw32 -lSDL2 -lC:\C_libraries\SDL2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\C_libraries\SDL2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\fersa\OneDrive\Documentos\Random Stuff\

Comment: `-L` is used to specify a directory to look for libraries in. `-l` is used to specify a particular library file. It looks like you are using lowercase for both options.